# Accessing Coherence Cache hosted on Weblogic 12c from Java Client

Tags: caching, weblogic12c

I would like to access and manipulate Coherence Cache configured on a cluster defined with in WebLogic 12c as a GAR via API in an java application.

Though I can get a reference to cache via NamedCache API but am unable to get objects added to it via web logic JSP page.

Any tips will be appreciated

Comment: Can you add some code to explain what you are trying to do? Something like this: https://blogs.oracle.com/middlewareplace/entry/calculating_the_size_of_a

Comment: I want to access cache hosted on Weblogic12c from a standalone java application.

Comment: Here's the code snapshot NamedCache cache = CacheFactory.getCache("myCache");
  
// Fetch the reference of Cache Service   
CacheService cacheService  = cache.getCacheService();
  
System.out.println("Service is : "+cacheService);
Set keys = cache.keySet();

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have the same cluster and cache configuration, all you have to do from your stand-alone Java process is to call into the CacheFactory class and ask for the cache.